# How to Collect fraction in Maple 18?

Tags: maple

Suppose I have

$$f=\frac x 3+ \frac y 3 +\frac z 3$$

And I want to use

```
collect(f, 1/3)
```

And I wish it will displays

$$f=\frac1 3(x+y+z)$$

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> f:=x/3+y/3+z/3;   
> desired_factor:=1/3;
> ``(desired_factor)*map(t->t/desired_factor,f);
```

does what you want (but with parentheses around the 1/3)